# UDP-приёмник сообщений на C++ Qt или Python PyQt

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt

Необходимо разработать UDP-приёмник, принимающий строку данных от сервера на другом ПК, и помещающий спец. информацию в окно в соответствии с принятой строкой. Строка содержит координаты расположения надписи для окна и содержание надписи. Окно с названием, без кнопок, надписи выводятся координатно - два столбца в несколько строк. 
На чём проще и быстрее написать это приложение с использованием библиотеки Qt - на С++ или Python ?

Comment: Что лучше знаете, на том и быстрее

Comment: Delphi: 10 минут на написание, 30 на отладку и форматирование кода.

Comment: Не очень понятно откуда требование Qt. Если это standalone приложение, то проще всего скрипт на Tcl/Tk